# javascript - what does this line mean: var result = original.apply(this, arguments)

Tags: javascript

just started learning javascript from the book the definitive guide, there is one line which I couldn't figure it out. Here is the complete code:

```
// Replace the method named m of the object o with a version that logs
// messages before and after invoking the original method.
function trace(o, m) {
    var original = o[m]; // Remember original method in the closure.
    o[m] = function() { // Now define the new method.
        console.log(new Date(), "Entering:", m); // Log message.
        var result = original.apply(this, arguments); // Invoke original.
        console.log(new Date(), "Exiting:", m); // Log message.
        return result; // Return result.
    };
}
```

the author did not comment on the line and I have a few questions regarding this code.

1. What does **this**, **arguments** refer to respectively? How is this invocation works exactly?

Explanations on the closures in this particular code would be welcomed too!
Thank you

Comment: Start your research with this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Comment: This is called _decoration_, doing this implements a decorator pattern.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Answer (score 1):

`apply` is invoking the function referenced by `o[m]`, using `this` as the "context" and forwarding the `arguments` passed to the replacement function onto the original function.

The "context" is referring to the "this"-binding of the function. If you were to say `var result = original.apply(null, arguments);` then the "context" would be set to `null`, and any call to "this" in the original function would (more or less) be replaced by "null".

In this case, calls to `this` in `m` are probably expected to refer to `o`, since it is the containing object.

Comment: It is true, though I think it would be good to mention `this` here is probably expected to be `o`.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript binds the special [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) and [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) variables when a function is called: `this` refers to the function's caller and `arguments` stores all passed arguments in an array-like object. The line `original.apply(this, arguments)` invokes the function `original` with the same `this` binding and the same arguments, in the same order, as the function in which the line occurs (here, an anonymous function stored at `o[m]`).